# Getting the current release version from Jenkins and pass it as a parameter

Tags: maven, jenkins, parameter-passing

I am new to DevOps and Jenkins and I want to ask you something. I'll try to simply explain my need hoping for helpful suggestions from you, so here we start :

To **Perform a Maven Release**, I need to specify the version of the current release in my **pom.xml** file

```
<carbon.appmgt.version>${version.release}</carbon.appmgt.version>
```

To do so, I am using :

```
-Darguments='-Dversion.release=VALUE'
```

in **Goals and Option** input in **Build** section as this [image](http://postimg.org/image/s3hs1bakx/) shows

Now the problem is that I want Jenkins to put the current release version for me in the place of **VALUE**

Comment: Try formatting it as: "-Darguments='-Dversion.release=${VALUE}'" and setting this VALUE parameter as one of the job's parameters...

Comment: add a `String Build Parameter` to your jenkins job, say `Value` be that parameter you can use it as $Value wherever you want

Comment: Thank you guys but this way I'll need to specify the version manually while I need to read it automatically fom Jenkins

Comment: has this question been answered ? I am also interested about a solution to it.